# intermediate mutate (/merge) based on multiple joins

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following somewhat complicated problem. Consider the following two data frames

```
df
  ID cat month_1 month_2
1  1   A       3       1
2  1   B       2       2
3  1   C       3       4
4  2   A       3       6
5  3   D       5       2
6  3   B       2       9
> df2
  ID month_number
1  1      month_1
2  1      month_2
3  2      month_1
4  2      month_2
5  3      month_1
6  3      month_2
```

Now, I want to do the following: I want to create a new column in `df2`, displaying the sum of an related to the ID, in the specific month. I.e., in the first df it can be seen that the person with ID 1 has a total sum of 3+2+3 = 8 in month 1 and 7 in month 2. I want to mutate this, respectively to the correct month. The desired output would be (Now computed by hands)

```
desired_df
  ID month_number grand_total
1  1      month_1           8
2  1      month_2           7
3  2      month_1           3
4  2      month_2           6
5  3      month_1           7
6  3      month_2          11
```

I want to show my code, but I do not have any. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Merge/join by ID and summarise? Actually looks like `melt`ing df might be sufficient.

Comment: But how does the computer know to which month he should map it, as in ```df``` the month number is displayed as a column title

Comment: Try this with `dplyr` and `tidyr`: `df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(contains("month"),"key",values_to = "val") %>% 
  group_by(key,cat) %>% 
  summarise(Sum =sum(val))`

Comment: Alright! I'll be on it right know

Comment: ```library(dplyr);
library(tidyr);

df1 %>%
  select(-cat) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum) %>% 
  gather(month_number, grand_total, -ID)```

Comment: Or ```df1 %>%
  gather(month_number, grand_total, -c(ID,cat)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, month_number) %>% 
  summarise(grand_total = sum(grand_total))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do once you get the data into "tidy" format, which we can do using `gather` (at some point this will be replaced by pivot_longer as NelsonGon commented above, but that's not in the CRAN release yet). I've used `contains("month")` to select all of the columns that contain that string, but if you have actual month names as columns, you could do `Jan:Dec` or literally type them out to select them instead. At that point, `group_by` your identifier column(s) and then use `summarize` to compute your sum within each group.

```
df %>% 
  gather(key = "month_number", value = "count", contains("month")) %>% 
  group_by(ID, month_number) %>% 
  summarize(grand_total = sum(count))
```

There's no reason to join in this instance since gather does what you need.